# Setting up manager role for Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7

I am trying to setup username and password to gain access to the Tomcat Manager App.  I've followed a bunch of different advices which I found in similar posts, yet I'm still unable to successfully login.  Here is my tomcat-users.xml file:

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="pass" roles='admin-gui,manager-gui'/>
</tomcat-users>
```

After inserting admin as the username and pass as the password I get the same login prompt box.  If I hit cancel I get a 401 Unauthorized page.

I started Tomcat via the command line by typing:

```
$ chmod a+x *.sh
$ ./startup.sh
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to shutdown the server and startup again.

```
$ ./shutdown.sh
$ ./startup.sh
```

Enter username and password and access granted.

Comment: Exactly, you need to shut it down first. Restart did not work for me.